# Hidden hotkeys in the 2.8

Tags: shortcut

I can not find many hotkeys in the "Keymap", but they are searchable. I need find where they are, because I want to add more variants.

Is it bug or it is hidden somewhere?

For example "Time scub" or "Gizmo":

[image: Time scrub]

[image: Gizmo]

Answer (score 1):

The gizmo category is not included in the [`keymap_hierarchy.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/modules/bl_keymap_utils/keymap_hierarchy.py) which can be found in `release\scripts\modules\bl_keymap_utils`. Therefore the category isn't displayed in the overview of the keymap. When you export the keymap you can view all shortcuts and it includes the ones for the gizmos.

It's not entirely clear to me why these entries are missing, hence I've created ticket [T77799](https://developer.blender.org/T77799) on Blender's bug tracker. The reply by the UI team will be your definitive answer.

Comment: Why would you consider it a missing feature? Looks like a bug to me. The feature here would be to list all hotkeys for user to modify, wouldn't it? If the list is incomplete, it means it is not functioning as it should. If it was fixed, there would be no new functionality added, would there? I think it should be considered to be a bug and then reported as such. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys The default view of the keymap tries to have an organized hierarchy. I'd have to check with the UI team if it was intentional to exclude some in order to reduce clutter or if it should be displayed as their own category. I might also be missing something and they are somewhere in there but as a subcategory (it's almost a year since I've taken a look at it). Will take a look, but likely not before the next weekend.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I've created a ticket for this [T77799](https://developer.blender.org/T77799), since Campbell Barton also suggested that this could be a bug.